# Jira: Filter for ALL issues on projects on which I've been involved

Tags: jira

Here is what I'm looking for in SQL:

```
select * from issues i1 
where exists ( 
    select '' 
    from issues i2 
    where 
         i1.projectid = i2.projectid 
         and 
         i2.userid = :currentUser 
)
```

Anyone know how to write that for the Jira query language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Participants field as cf[10150] you can do stuff like this

cf[10150] = currentUser() or issue in votedIssues() or issue in watchedIssues()

For your SQL, you can find issues where you're the assignee, or reporter etc using similar standard JQL functions.